# How can $ P\big(|X_n| \geq \varepsilon\big) \leq P\big(\big|X_n-\frac{1}{n}\big| \geq \varepsilon+\frac{1}{n}\big) $?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, random-variables, cumulative-distribution-functions

I am following a probability course on MIT OCW, and on a tutorial on probability convergence, in an attempt to use the **Chebyshev's Inequality** to prove it, the TA claimed that
$$
P\big(|X_n| \geq \varepsilon\big) \leq P\bigg(\bigg|X_n-\frac{1}{n}\bigg| \geq \varepsilon+\frac{1}{n}\bigg).
$$
To prove it, he said *"The right hand side will cover less of $X_n$ hence the inequality holds".*
[image]

Shouldn't **"covering less"** of the random variable result in less probability, and not more?
Am I missing something or did he made a mistake?

[Link for the [video](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/6-041sc-probabilistic-systems-analysis-and-applied-probability-fall-2013/resources/convergence-in-probability-and-in-the-mean-part-1/), discussed around 8:10.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TA made a sign error.  It should have read

$$\mathbb{P}(|X_n| \geq \varepsilon) \leq \mathbb{P}\left(\left|X_n - \frac1n\right| \geq \varepsilon - \frac1n\right)$$

The rest of the argument follows as expected for any $n > \frac1\varepsilon$, hence it works in the limit as $n\to\infty$ as well.

Comment: I think since the problem states that Xn is non-negative, so $P(Xn<-ϵ−\frac{2}{n})$ will be zero since both ϵ and n are non-negative by definition, Doesn't this make them equal in this case?

Comment: @user28324 Again, I don't know where you're getting the probability in your comment.  Are you trying to write this? $$P(|X_n - \frac1n| \geq \varepsilon - \frac1n) = P(X_n \geq \varepsilon) + P(X_n \leq \frac2n - \varepsilon)$$  If so, then yes, you could note that for $n > \frac2\varepsilon$, the last probability would be $0$ for non-negative $X_n$, so for $n > \frac2\varepsilon$, the $\leq$ in my answer would become an equality.  This is a lot of work for very little payoff, though, since the inequality as I gave it holds independently of the particulars of $X_n$ and $n$.

Comment: yes, i realized my mistake, i forgot to multiply the -1/n with -1 , thats what i get for doing math at 3 am i guess
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The inequality is obviously wrong. $X_n=\frac 1 n$ with $0 <\epsilon <\frac 1 n$ gives a counter-example.

Comment: I think in the given example $X_n$  can take 1 and 0, the $\frac{1}{n}$ mentioned is $P_X(1)$.
That being said, a counterexample can be found easily, when I thought about it I found another argument against it relying on the fact that CDFs are monotonic

Answer (score 0):

Edit Note: I refer to the RHS of the equation in question as the second event, while the LHS is referred to as the first event.

Hmmm... Let me see if I can give it a shot(no guarantee if this is correct)

The inequality is incorrect and should actually face the other way. That is, $$P(|X_n| \geq \epsilon) \geq P(|X_n - \frac{1}{n}| \geq \epsilon + \frac{1}{n})$$

If we take the fist event and decompose it,

$$P(|X_n| \geq \epsilon) = P(X_n \geq \epsilon \cup -X_n \leq -\epsilon) \\ =P(X_n \geq \epsilon) +  P(-X_n \leq -\epsilon)$$

Does that make sense? The last equality comes from the fact that the events are disjoint.

Now on the other hand,
$$P(|X_n - \frac{1}{n}| \geq \epsilon + \frac{1}{n}) = P(X_n - \frac{1}{n} \geq \epsilon + \frac{1}{n}) + P(-X_n + \frac{1}{n} \leq -\epsilon - \frac{1}{n})$$
Simplifying the algebra inside the parenthesis now
$$P(|X_n - \frac{1}{n}| \geq \epsilon + \frac{1}{n}) = P(X_n \geq \epsilon + \frac{2}{n})+P(-X_n \leq -\epsilon - \frac{2}{n})$$

So now if we compare the two probabilities -

For first probability/event $X_n$ just has to be bigger than $\epsilon$ or $-X_n$ has to be smaller than$-\epsilon$. On the other hand, for the second probability/event $X_n$ has to be bigger than $\epsilon$ **PLUS** $\frac{2}{n}$ or $X_n$ has to be smaller than $-\epsilon$ **MINUS** $\frac{2}{n}$

So the second probability is less likely of happening because we have more conditions(on X_n) needed to satisfy the event happening. Said differently, the probability space for the second event happening is smaller than the probability space of the first event happening.

Comment: shouldn't $P(|X_n−\frac{1}{n}|≥ϵ+\frac{1}{n})=P(X_n−\frac{1}{n}≥ϵ+\frac{1}{n})+P(−X_n+\frac{1}{n}≤−ϵ−\frac{1}{n})$ be $P(|X_n−\frac{1}{n}|≥ϵ+\frac{1}{n})=P(X_n−\frac{1}{n}≥ϵ+\frac{1}{n})+P(X_n-\frac{1}{n}≤−ϵ−\frac{1}{n})$ ? 
i think you added an extra negative